# Preciso colocar um link no meu Google Maps

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google, maps

Tenho um mapa no meu site, onde a localização do estabelecimento no mapa tem a logomarca, no lugar do PIN padrão do Google Maps, aparece um imagem em PNG.

Eu preciso que essa imagem, ao clicar, leve para uma URL especifica, dentro do próprio site. Já pesquisei alguns códigos, mas não deu certo.

Segue o meu código usado no site:

```
    <script>

// This example adds a marker to indicate the position of Bondi Beach in Sydney,
// Australia.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 18,
    center: {lat: -27.6041949, lng: -48.466012}
  });


  var image = 'img/marcador.png';
  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -27.6041949, lng: -48.466012},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AQUI_VAI_O_MEU_API_&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>

 <style>
     #map {
        height: 432px;
      }
    </style>
```

Desde já agradeço a colaboração de todos!

Comment: Já tentou um adicionar um listener que redireciona a url no marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente adicionar um `listener` para o evento click no `marker` como no exemplo abaixo. Usando a propriedade `window.location` você vai conseguir redirecionar para uma `path` dentro do site.

```
beachMarker.addListener('click', function() {
  window.location = '/index.html';
});
```

Informações sobre Markers da API do Google Maps [nesse link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers).

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado!!!